# Adding ssh public key from os x to ubuntu doesn't work

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, ssh, sshd

I've just switched my server to ubuntu and everything works except the ssh server. I've installed the sshd server and I generated on my mac ( client ) a key like this:

ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my@gmail.com" where my@gmail.com is my email I didn't know what else I needed to put here.

I copied the public ssh key from my mac to  my ubuntu server and added the content to the .ssh/authorized_keys file on ubuntu. I restarted the ssh server everything.

Now when I try to login via my mac with the command:

ssh 192.168.0.149 or even ssh my@192.168.0.149

I always get permission denied (publickey)

I don't know how to fix this? Can someone help me? I think it has something to do with the my@gmail.com but I don't know for sure. I just want to login from lan or from everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The line that defines the authorized_keys was commented. Uncommented this and everything works.